# Cygwin how do I install **all** packages

Tags: windows-8, cygwin

I want to install **all** packages from `cygwin` [here](https://cygwin.com/install.html) as well as is installed **Lynx** in the snippet below.
How do I check them all at one or two clicks so that I do not need go one item by other ?

What programs can I expect to obtain to be installed besides BASH like commands; there are hundreds of them ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjG7G.jpg)

Comment: Bad idea, install only what you need.  https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you follow the Cygwin setup and get to the select packages section.

In the view select '**Category**' and if it's already selected by default and you don't see packages classified as per category then just switch between the views and again select '**Category**'.

After that click on the '**-**' sign beside All and after that in the new tab where it shows default click and from the dropdown select '**install**'.
And click on 'next'

I Will be attaching a few images for reference.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qHnt.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zWBv.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzpCj.png)

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD0mf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Install all packages of cygwin](http://www.gohappycup.com/personal/latex/allpkg.html)
says this:

After you get the following window of cygwin setup

[image]

Click the word "Default" of the "All" package, so that the options after all packages become "Install". After the selection, the window looks like:

[image]